# Do people who go to swarga after death still have their earthly memories?

Tags: swarga

Do people who go to swarga after death still have their earthly memories?

Like do they still remember their human life? Or are they born in swarga and forget their past life on earth?

Comment: I believe some rebirth have previous memories that is well documented, that means if they have gone to swarga or narakha they still have the same memory but its hidden and  rebirth happens.. if they attain approksha gnana all the memory they can have access.. that is why all realized person gives accts of atleast 3 know birth.. Answer is Yes swarga memory is retained that is reason for Chandyogaupanishad where nachiketa remembers i have another also but i didnt remember